# ¿Como saber que tecla presionó el usuario sin detener la consola?

Tags: cmd, batch, msdos

Quiero hacer un juego en MS-DOS y estoy estancado con un problema:

> ¿Como pedir la entrada al usuario sin detener la consola?.

He considerado detenerla uno milisegundos y dar la ilucion de que la consola no se detuvo:

```
@echo off
:inicio
choice /c awds0 /t 0.30 /d 0
if %errorlevel%==1 echo izquierda.
goto inicio
pause
exit
```

Pero me genera un error:

> Solo se permite un numero del -1 a 999

Tambien he intentado colocar:

`choice /c awds0 /t 0 /d 0`

Pero no me dectecta la tecla aunque la ponga en un `bucle` goto:

```
@echo off
:inicio
choice /c awds0 /t 0 /d 0
if not %errorlevel%==5 goto end
goto inicio
:end
echo se terminó el programa
pause
exit
```

> input: a....

> output: Infinity loop

La otra opcion que pienso es capturar el evento click de la ventana, pero no sé como y no encuentro el como hacerlo.
  Nota: Uso windows 7 32bits. La consola que uso es la que trae por defecto el sistema operativo.

Enlaces externos:

- [Respuesta de: ¿Leer tecla en batch?](https://foro.elhacker.net/scripting/leer_tecla_en_batch-t269149.0.html;msg1318353#msg1318353) : Esta respuesta se acerca bastante a lo que yo busco, pero al ejecutarlo la consola se paraliza hasta que instrodusco la tecla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorprende en el 2021 un juego en lenguaje de comandos de [msdos](/questions/tagged/msdos). Das pocas pistas sobre la versión de [msdos](/questions/tagged/msdos) (o [mswindows](/questions/tagged/mswindows)) y si es de *32 o 64 bits*.

Para que el comando `CHOICE` pueda capturar algo del teclado, y no devuelva inmediatamente el valor por defecto, espera un número entero de segundos: entre 1 y 999. Si antes de terminar el tiempo se teclea algo lo captura y lo evalúa como ya sabes. El mínimo es un segundo (con 0 devolvería inmediatamente un valor por defecto y no nada que tecleemos).

Pero como indicas que SÍ puedes añadir un comando propio. Este código en C++, una vez compilado, hace lo que necesitas:

```
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
   if (_kbhit() == 0)
      return 0;
   else
      return _getch();
}
```

Lo compilo para mis pruebas con el nombre
PatxiRBGetKey.exe

El programa cuando se ejecuta NO se detiene.
Si no se ha tecleado nada devuelve un 0
Si se ha tecleado algo consume un carácter y devuelve el código ASCII que corresponde al mismo (no se mostrará nada en pantalla).

Puedes ver el valor devuelto con

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

Por ejemplo si se ha tecleado F mayúscula errorlevel tendría un 70
y si se ha tecleado f minúscula errorlevel tendría un 102 y si no se ha tecleado nada errorlevel tendría un 0

Uniéndolo todo y modificando ligeramente el BAT de #Sal

```
@echo off
cls
:inicio
PatxiRBGetKey.exe

if %errorlevel%==87 echo W arriba
if %errorlevel%==119 echo W arriba

if %errorlevel%==65 echo A izquierda
if %errorlevel%==97 echo a izquierda

if %errorlevel%==83 echo S derecha
if %errorlevel%==115 echo s derecha

if %errorlevel%==90 echo Z abajo
if %errorlevel%==122 echo z abajo

goto inicio
```

[image: ejecución del programa de prueba]

Animo y suerte.

Comment: Suena bastante interesante tu respuesta. Me gustaria que se pueda ejecutar en mayor cantidad de consola posible pero veo que eso es mas dificil de lo que creí. Tengo windows 7 32bits, la consola que uso es `CMD` que es casi como la antigua dos, pero extendido.

Comment: Si Dios quiere mañana pruevo esta respuesta.

Comment: Las restricciones del problema ¿es estrictamente obligatorio hacerlo todo con comandos oficiales de la consola cmd de Windows 7 o permitirían añadir un programa propio: miGetkey.exe que permitan un choice que trabaje en milisegundos y no en segundos?

Comment: Probé el código en windows 7 32bits y al ejecutarse el programa se detiene diciendo: `ilegal instruccion in ms-dos 16bits` , pero creo que entiendo la idea: Si los comando existente no te sirve, crea un nuevo comando o una nueva aplicacion que se apdate a tus nesecidades. No se como hacerlo pero ya creo tener una pista.

Comment: Ahora por problemas personales no creo poder compilar y provar tú código dentro de los siguientes tres dias.

Comment: Gracias funcionó. Antes de esta respuesta no sabia que hacia conio.h y ahora lo sé. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Con respecto a ¿Como pedir la entrada al usuario sin detener la consola?, veo que usas choice pero obtienes el error

> Solo se permite un numero del -1 a 999

Te sugiero usar:

```
timeout /t <numero de segundos a esperar>
```

ejemplo, de esta forma esperarías a recibir una tecla para que el programa continue:

```
@echo off
:inicio
timeout /t 10 & :: Espera 10 segundos
if %errorlevel%==1 echo izquierda.
goto inicio
pause
exit
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora con respecto a saber que tecla presionó el usuario.

editando...

Comment: Me parece interesante tu respuesta, pero no es la que buscaba porque intento colocar un `echo` abajo del comando `timeout` se nota que la consola espera a que termine el comando `timeout`. Lo que necesito es saber que tecla presiona el usuario mientras se va dibujando el mapa por el comando `echo`. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

En [ms-dos](/questions/tagged/ms-dos) el manejo de la entrada es sumamente limitada, lo más lejos que llegarías sería a algo esto:

```
@echo off
:inicio
cls
if %errorlevel%==0 echo ---
if %errorlevel%==5 echo ---
if %errorlevel%==1 echo izq
if %errorlevel%==2 echo arr
if %errorlevel%==3 echo aba
if %errorlevel%==4 echo der
choice /T 1 /C awsdl /D l
goto inicio
```